# Cannot alter assembly on SQL Server DB

Tags: .net, sql-server

I recently installed a .NET security update on one of our database servers.  Now, when I try to query this database, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Assembly in host store has a different signature than assembly in GAC

Per various Google results, Stack Overflow responses, and [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-6522-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16), we tried running the following command:

```
ALTER ASSEMBLY [System.IO.FileLoadException] FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.IO.Compression.dll'
```

But receive the following error:

> Cannot alter the assembly 'System.IO.FileLoadException', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

The file in question *does* exist, and I am logged in as a domain admin and am using the DB's 'sa' credentials which should have full privileges, so also not sure how it could be a permission issue.

(Also tried just restarting the server, which didn't fix anything.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the new version of any .NET Framework assemblies you have loaded into the database after the update.

Note this is why loading extra .NET Framework assemblies for use in SQLCLR is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

`FileLoadException` is the *error*. The actual assembly that errored is `System.DirectoryServices`, this is probably because it is a dependency of something else, and the strong name (public key token) has changed.

And you need `CREATE` not `ALTER`. You may need to drop the existing one first.

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.DirectoryServices]
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.DirectoryServices.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
```

---

To get the right permissions to do this, you may need the following, see also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/assemblies/creating-an-assembly?view=sql-server-ver16#creating-external_access-and-unsafe-assemblies):

```sql
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY DotNetSigningKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.DirectoryServices.dll';
CREATE LOGIN DotNetSigningLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY DotNetSigningKey;
GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO DotNetSigningLogin;
```

Another alternative is to set your database to `TRUSTWORTHY`, however this is not recommended unless your SQL Server is heavily locked down and not accessible over the network, due to security concerns.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  
  
I tried the following:  
  
`CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.DirectoryServices]
FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.DirectoryServices.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL`  
  
And get:  
  
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXTERNAL'`  
  
When I try:  
  
`DROP ASSEMBLY [System.DirectoryServices]`  
  
I get:  
  
`Cannot drop the assembly 'System.DirectoryServices', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Comment: Thank you!  Now, I am getting the following error:  `CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' failed because assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS.  The assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the database owner (DBO) has EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY permission.`

Comment: Would it be possible to temporarily set the DB as `TRUSTWORTHY`, make the changes, then remove the `TRUSTWORTHY` property?  If it wasn't obvious, I have exceedingly little knowledge/experience with MSSQL DB administration, but I'm currently all we've got, so I'm trying my best.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: No, you won't be able to access any of the assembly functions in that case. You need to do one or the other of those instructions. See edit